# Var args Autowire

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

I'm want to auto wire the beans which are the var args aruments for my constructor.

**Can I do that, if yes how can I achieve?**

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
Public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
    private Set<Rules> rules = new HashSet<Rules>(); 

    public ServiceImpl(Rules... args) {
        for (Rules r : args) {
            rules.add(r);
        } 
    }
    //...
}
```

I'm trying to inject in `spring-config.xml` like below:

```
<bean id = "check" class="ServiceImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="notEmpty"></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="check"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this with annotations and without passing `constructor args` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with annotations you can add @Autowired to the constructor and the IoC container will wire in all the Rules instances that are registered in the context:

```
@Component
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
private Set<Rules> rules = new HashSet<Rules>(); 

@Autowired
public ServiceImpl(Rules... args) {
    for (Rules r : args) {
        rules.add(r);
    } 
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting No qualifying bean exception, Here is my spring-config.xml

 <context:component-scan base-package="passwordcheck" />
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/Jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
</beans>

Comment: that means the context cannot find any Rules implementations. You need to ensure you have at least 1 concrete implementation of Rules in your application context (something annotated with @Component in the package(s) you're scanning).